# Unpublish, Trash or Delete buttons in the Frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor, workflow

I want to create some of these buttons in the frontend List view. I added checkboxes to the table and used the [Using_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend) tutorial to put `Save` and `Cancel` buttons.
Also added the Unpublish button with

```
$this->bar->appendButton( 'Frontend', 'unpublish', 'Unpublish', 'articles.unpublish', false );
```

But can't make it work to unpublish articles.
I put it in the same form as the table, so the action url is the same too, in my case:

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=8&Itemid=116
```

It just redirects to the page without messages (error level is maximum).

Can't find how the admin Unpublish button works.
So maybe someone worked with these buttons.

---

It looks like this.
[image]
The New Record button works, it uses this code:

```
$this->bar->appendButton( 'Standard', 'add', 'New Record', 'article.add', false );
```

Comment: Does user have the rights to execute these actions? E.g. manager

Comment: Registered user has

Answer (score 1):

There is no controller for articles in the frontend. That's why `articles.unpublish` won't work. The toolbar itself is very flexible, but the default buttons just trigger a specific method of a controller.

Examples:

`article.add` will trigger `ContentArticleController->add()`

`articles.publish` will trigger `ContentArticlesController->publish()`